# How to set VS Code's Explorer width?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Does VS Code have separate settings for the Explorer panel size?

I want to hardcode those values and don't resize them every time, or just change the pixels value and get the new width.

Comment: You might want to vote this on VS Code's issues page: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/75017